# How to always include a model for eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I use the bullet gem to let me know of N+1 queries.

I want to avoid adding include sporadically.

I have a `comment` model which belongs to a `user` model

Is there a way to tell the model that anytime a comment model is being accessed to include the user as well? (instead of doing `Comment.include(:user)` everytime)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `default_scope`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope includes(:user)
end

Comment.first # => the same as Comment.includes(:user).first
```

Comment: thanks, how do I use that with   `default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'`?

Comment: Try `default_scope includes(:user).order("created_at desc")`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { includes(:user) }
end
```